# Wow js is not working with the Fullpage JS

Tags: javascript, animation, fullpage.js, wow.js

I'm adding the ZoomIn animation on the pageload on the image. But animation is not working due to FullpageJS.

Here is my code

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="0.5s" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
   <img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(function () {
    new WOW().init();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        // Options
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            autoScrolling: true,
            scrollHorizontally: true,
            scrollingSpeed: 1300,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            slidesNavigation: true,            
            afterRender: function () {
                new WOW().init();
            },
            afterLoad: function () {
                new WOW().init();
            }
        });
        //methods
        $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the fullpage.js option `scrollBar:true` on its initialisation.

This way fullPage.js will scroll using a scroll bar which is what wow.js requires in order to fire the scroll event it uses to trigger animations.

Comment: It is working, But when I set the scrollBar option true, the Page is shaking while scrolling.